# Nextjs pass cookie from external API and set on calling domain

Tags: express, cookies, next.js

I have a Nextjs app running at domain like https://client.mydomain.com that makes calls, from **browser** not getServerSideProps or micro api, to Express API at https://api.mydomain.com. The API returns a cookie (Secure, SameSite='none', long Expires), I can see the cookie in the response, and subsequent calls to the API from the **browser** will include the cookie correctly, but the cookie is not ever set on https://client.mydomain.com. So if I return to https://client.mydomain.com, the cookie is not present. Like it somehow pertains to the shared singleton axios instance.

How do I allow the cookie to pass through correctly from the API domain > client domain? > browser to be set on https://client.mydomain.com? I can extract the cookie from API in the axios call response in the client browser and manually set it via `document.cookie` of course, but sure I can simply allow it to pass through somehow from the API?

**Express**

`https://api.mydomain.com`

```
...
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ['https://client.mydomain.com', 'https://localhost:80'],
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: 'Set-Cookie',
  }),
);
...
res.cookie('mycookie', 'hello', {
   sameSite: 'none',
   secure: true,
   expires: tokenExpires,
});  
...
```

**Next.js App**

`https://client.mydomain.com`

```
const response = await axios.get('/', {
   withCredentials: true,
});
```

**Response Header**

```
set-cookie: mycookie=hello; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 29 Apr 2022 21:43:00 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None
```

Yet no cookie persisted if I check the application tab in chrome, or run `document.cookie` after the requests to API

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)?